# How do I create a folder using the date and time?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I'm trying to do a quick and simple game backup script and it's not working for me. Here's what I have.

```
   @echo off

:main

RD /S /Q "C:\Users\Citadel\Desktop\Minecraft_Backups"

mkdir "C:\Users\Citadel\Desktop\Minecraft_Backups\%date% - %time%"

XCOPY "C:\Users\Citadel\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\saves" "C:\Users\Citadel\Desktop\Minecraft_Backups\%date% - %time%" /D /E /C /R /I /K /Y

echo %date% - %time% - Backup Complete >> log.txt

PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 900000 >NUL

goto main
```

Honestly the mkdir command was a shot in the dark, but nothing so far has worked so I tried it.

Comment: Well it's an example of a problem I've been having for a while. Can't get any backup scripts to work since I use this format for all of them and just retrofit it.

Comment: Because I'm not that good at programming and batch can do the job while being easily editable at the same time. I'd write it in Python, but again, I don't know how to make a folder using the date and time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `%date%` and `%time%` contain special characters that can't be used in directory names. Try this at the top of your script:

```
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a%%b)
```

Or if you prefer 24-hour time, change the second line to:

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set mytime=%%a%%b)
```

And then use `%mydate%_%mytime%` in place of `%date% %time%`.

Note that this may have regional issues, but if you confirm it working for your machine, for local backups it will always be fine.

Comment: Thanks. I'd vote up but I don't have the rep for it. XD Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found that seems to work:

```
@setlocal enableextensions
set datestamp=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~7,2%
mkdir %datestamp%
```

Comment: this does not include time